# While executing cgi,plain text is displayed

Tags: python, apache, cgi, yocto

- I have enabled apache2 on imx6ul board which is running on custom modified Linux kernel.
- On running the CGI-script the contents are displayed in a plain text format. The code is working fine on my personal pc.
- How do I enable CGI in embedded Linux distributions?
- The custom Linux is built using YOCTO project for imx6ul board and base BSP provided by the vendor.
- The configuration file in the filesystem is named httpd.conf instead of apache2.conf.